# Replace div with td in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I wrote the following code to toggle between showing and hiding content. This works fine.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse in">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
```

Is it possible to replace **div** content with couple of **tds**?

```
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

Seems to be working fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Yes you can replace div content with couple of tds.

 <div id="demo" class="collapse">
  <table>
   <tr><td> Content </td></tr>
   <tr><td> Content </td></tr>
   <tr><td> Content </td></tr>

  </table>


  </div>
```